# GET variable passed with jquery

Tags: php, jquery, css

this is my jQuery function

```
start: function() {
            var text;

            if(($('#choose2').css('display')!='none')){
                    text=$( "#select option:selected" ).text();
                    $('#1').load(this.path+'\compile.php?file=' +text).show();

            }else if(($('#choose3').css('display')!='none')){
                    text=$( "#select option:selected" ).text();
                    $('#1').load(this.path+'\execute.php?file=' +text).show();

            }
    }
```

This is the problem: the `compile.php` works fine and the results will show in div with `id=1`, but `execute.php` page works with the same GET var passed before to `compile.php` (also if I select an other file from the select box). If I don't use `compile.php` before, the `execute.php` doesn't work. For testing I used in `compile.php`:

```
echo 'This is the file to compile '.$_GET['file'];
```

and in `execute.php`:

```
echo 'This is the file to execute '.$_GET['file'];
```

but as I wrote, the file remains the same. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a  client side or server side check  to make sure compile.php has been invoked before execute.php for any file

You can store it in the session or cookie or even client side you can keep track of it.

Comment: In the server I have a directory with .c files and an other for .out files, so the users can execute directly a file compiled (for example) 2 weeks ago. The problem is $_GET['file'], it doesn't work in execute.php